# Combine 2 multi-line selections Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I've been looking to combine two multi-line selections in Sublime Text and have not been successful in finding an answer

Expample:

starting information:

```
part1 from ...
part2 from ...
part3 from ...
part4 from ...
...
part100 from ...
```

and I am given a list like:

```
MFR2
MFR1
MFR4
MFR2
MFR6
MFR1
MFR4
etc.
```

which I hope to combine into:

```
part1 from MFR2 ...
part2 from MFR1 ...
part3 from MFR4 ...
part4 from MFR2 ...
part5 from MFR6 ...
part6 from MFR1 ...
part7 from MFR4 ...
etc.
```

Is there any way that I can do this within Sublime Text?

Comment: As I undestand, the content are in two diferent files, in the first one you have multiple cursors (no selections), and in the second file you have a list that you want to copy to the curors positions. Is that right? Remember that you can [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31191146/edit) to add more info.

Comment: Then Avalanche answer should ve valid for you.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem you should accept it (check the green tick at the left of the answer). [More info on how accept works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Text Pastry](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Text%20Pastry), it gives you more features when working with multiple cursors. You can check what things you can do with it in their [Wiki Example page](https://github.com/duydao/Text-Pastry/wiki/Examples). I think it should cover your need.